# The table grid is not displayed Ui_component

Tags: magento2

> layout

```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Feedback</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="menu">
            <action method="setActive">
                <argument name="itemId" xsi:type="string">RonisBt_Feedback::feedback</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="feedback_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    </page>
```

> ui_component

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">feedback_listing.feedback_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">feedback_listing.feedback_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">feedback_feedback_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="feedback_listing_data_source">
        <dataSource name="feedback_listing_data_source">
            <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">feedback_listing_data_source</argument>
                <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">feedback_id</argument>
                <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">feedback_id</argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                        <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                        <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">feedback_id</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </argument>
        </dataSource>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters">

        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">

        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
    </listingToolbar>

    <columns name="feedback_feedback_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">feedback_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="feedback_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Created</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Modified</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="feedback_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">RonisBt\Feedback\Model\ResourceModel\Feedback\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this di.xml file**

```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="feedback_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">RonisBt\Feedback\Model\ResourceModel\Feedback\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
   </type>
   <virtualType name="RonisBt\Feedback\Model\ResourceModel\Feedback\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">table_name</argument>
        <!-- add your table name --->
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">RonisBt\Feedback\Model\ResourceModel\Feedback\</argument>
    </arguments>
   </virtualType>
```